# Не могу понять в чем ошибка, я новичок

Tags: python-3.x

```
what = int(input('Что делаем (+,-?):'))
a = int(input('Введи первое число:'))
b = int(input('Введи второе число:'))
if what =='+'
c = a + b
print('Результат:', c)
elif what =='-'
c = a - b
print('Результат:', c)
else:
print('Выбрана неверная операция!')
```

Comment: Какую ошибку показывает компилятор?

Comment: invalid syntax в 4 строке где "+"

Comment: После условий if-elif всегда должны стоять двоеточия, а у вас их нет

Comment: Потому что вы забыли поставить `:` в конце. Идем дальше, теперь, видимо, будут ошибки с отступами - для питона это критично

Comment: о, так я правку с этими добавами опубликовал. Ждет проверки=)

Comment: все))) всем спасибо

Comment: @Dmitry а вот так нельзя делать - иначе не вырастет программист )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я не хотел=) честно. Но это лучшее, что случилось за сегодня=) ТС воспользуйтесь готовыми решениями, чтобы не допускать таких ошибок. Например, установите VSCode.

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо, за откат, не хотел и прочитал невнимательно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Поставим пробел после :, чтобы аргумент "не слипался"
# По умолчанию input() считывает строку. Ты пытаешься привести строку
# к int. Так делать нельзя. Поэтому уберем приведение типов int
what = input('Что делаем (+,-?): ')

a = int(input('Введи первое число: '))
b = int(input('Введи второе число: '))

# Уберем ненужную временную переменную c и поставим двоеточия.
# Также, расставим отступы для удобочитаемости и самого запуска т.к.
# в Python без отступов код не запускается.

if what == '+':
    print('Результат: ', a + b)
elif what == '-':
    print('Результат: ', a - b)
else:
    print('Выбрана неверная операция!')
```

Answer (score 3):

1. После условий в if/elif/else **обязательно** должны стоять знаки двоеточия ( : );
2. Во время перехода к операциям внутри if/elif/else Вы должны делать отступ в четыре пробела (через Tab). Без них интерпретатор не сможет обработать Ваш код, да и вообще во вложенных ситуациях (циклы, условные операторы, функции и пр.) следует использовать только отступы в 4 пробела.

Иными словами, Ваш код можно переписать как-то так:

```
what = int(input('Что делаем (+,-?):'))
a = int(input('Введи первое число:'))
b = int(input('Введи второе число:'))
if what == '+':
  c = a + b
  print('Результат:', c)
elif what == '-':
  c = a - b
  print('Результат:', c)
else:
  print('Выбрана неверная операция!')
```

З.Ы. @Dmitry, лучше уж верный вариант привести в комментариях, а не редачить исходный код вопроса >.<

Comment: А вы меня жизни поучите=)

Comment: Увы, в комментариях многострочный код нельзя вставить. Всё превратится в одну строчку. Так только хуже будет.

Comment: @Dmitry если что, простите, но всё же вдруг потом кто-то зайдёт сюда, увидет исправленный код и в комментариях начнёт гнобить товарища словами типа "дык всё же было правильно, чего ты сюда пишешь???7", а в комментарии прочие может и поленится заглянуть >.<

Comment: @GrAnd имел в виду ответы-комментарии, виноват

Comment: @4500zenja смотрите мои комментарии под вопросом. Гнобить могут начать за хамство, да за игнорирование правил. Очень редко кто не за дело получает. Стоп флуд, все это не относится у вопросу

Comment: еще в 1 строке int не нужен